# Good Sound Classes/Libraries for Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, audio, volume, playback

Can anyone recommend good sound classes or libraries (open-source) for Actionscript 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think André Michelle has a nice library, though the docs are sometimes sparse: [Tonfall](http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2010/tonfall-open-source-audio-framework/)

Answer (score 1):

The comments on this library look good. I haven't tried it, but plan on it.

[StandingWaves3 Library for Flash from Joe Berkovitz](http://joeberkovitz.com/blog/2009/05/15/standingwave-open-source-as3-audio/)

I've been looking at this javascript sound generator to see if there's a chance it could be ported to ActionScript.

[JSFX javascript audio generator](http://egonelbre.com/js/jsfx/)

There's a similar topic over at FlashDevelop, mentions PopForge:

flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3595